# Value of property in JSON object gets converted to 0 in Spring Rest Controller

Tags: java, json, spring

I am passing an array of JSON objects from Angular1.x front end to Spring RestController backend. 
The value is correct in browser's HTTP request payload but in Spring RestController one of the property is getting converted to Zero.

I am unable to debug the reason. Please help me.

Below is the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z5ZX.png)snapshot of the request payload in browser

[{"articleID ":"17070","productCode":"1000","productName":"Business Parcel zone ","zone":"1"},{"articleID ":"17071","productCode":"1001","productName":"Business Parcel zone ","zone":"4"},{"articleID ":"17070","productCode":"1012","productName":"Business Parcel zone ","zone":"5"},{"articleID ":"17070","productCode":"1000","productName":"Business Parcel zone ","zone":"1"},{"articleID ":"17070","productCode":"1000","productName":"Business Parcel zone ","zone":"2"}]

Below is the Code of my Controller :

```
 @RestController
 public class MyController {

 @Autowired
 MyService MyService;


  @RequestMapping(value = "/savedata",  method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ServiceArticle> saveData(@RequestBody List<ServiceArticle> serviceArticleList){
    System.out.println("In savedata");
    System.out.println(serviceArticleList.toString());

    if(null != serviceArticleList && serviceArticleList.size() >0){
        MyService.addAll(serviceArticleList);
    }

    //  ResponseEntity<ServiceArticle> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<ServiceArticle>(serviceArticle, HttpStatus.OK);

    return null;
}   

}
```

This is the result of invoking toString() on the JSON object array received in the Spring RestController

[ServiceArticle [articleID=0, productCode=1000, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=1], ServiceArticle [articleID=0, productCode=1001, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=4], ServiceArticle [articleID=0, productCode=1012, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=5], ServiceArticle [articleID=0, productCode=1000, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=1], ServiceArticle [articleID=0, productCode=1000, productName=Business Parcel zone , zone=2]]

articleID comes as 0 in all the ServiceArticle objects in the Array. This is the issue I am trying to figure out. articleID is correct in request payload but converts to 0 in RestController.

Below is the code of my Java Object which binds to JSON object in RequestBody

```
public class ServiceArticle {

private long articleID;
private long productCode;
private String productName;
private int zone;

public ServiceArticle(){
    super();
}

public ServiceArticle(long articleID, long productCode, String productName, int zone) {
    super();
    this.articleID = articleID;
    this.productCode = productCode;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.zone = zone;
}

public long getArticleID() {
    return articleID;
}

public void setArticleID(long articleID) {
    this.articleID = articleID;
}

public long getProductCode() {
    return productCode;
}

public void setProductCode(long productCode) {
    this.productCode = productCode;
}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public int getZone() {
    return zone;
}

public void setZone(int zone) {
    this.zone = zone;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ServiceArticle [articleID=" + articleID + ", productCode=" + productCode + ", productName="
            + productName + ", zone=" + zone + "]";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your input JSON. You've provided a space in `"articleID "`. Change `"articleID "` to `"articleID"`

Comment: Thank you @BeginnersSake, it worked. You are a genius.